# Make one DEM file with the lowest points of two overlapping DEM files with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator

I have two rasters DEM files which are exactly overlapping. Now I want to have a new file with the lowest points from both DEMs. I think Raster calculator can do such things, but I dont know how. How can I do this?

Comment: Please define "lowest points". Which data type do your DEM have? What have you tried?

Comment: i did have 2 elevation DEMs with different z coordinates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the raster calculator, use the `MIN` function:

```
 MIN ( "raster1@1","raster2@1")
```