# How to replace bathymetry in a DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, merge

I have a merit DEM TIFF file and in that file, I simply wish to replace some values by taking values from another TIFF file that has bathymetry data for a lake.

Can I do this using a raster calculator? I tried the merge option but the result is coming out as the same merit TIFF file as before.

I need to replace the values of a small part in DEM by using another TIFF file as new values and just replace them straight forward.

Comment: Do they have the same extent and resolution? What value(s) does the other raster have outside the lake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine a topographic DEM with an overlapping bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427880/how-to-combine-a-topographic-dem-with-an-overlapping-bathymetry)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the `gdal:merge` tool, and it worked. The order in which you add the files is important. This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75202479 says that it takes the last value that is written.

So make sure you click your "large" DEM first and the bathymetrie DEM second in the merge options.

I have my large DEM from SRTM and a small DEM that has a value of 777 in every cell. Cell sizes are the same as the large DEM.

This is the large DEM before the merge:

[image: original DEM]

In the merge tool under "input layers" (probably, I only have a german QGIS) click in this order:

[image: input click order]

First the large DEM, second the lake DEM.

Click OK in the upper(!) right panel to get back to the base tool dialog, then run the tool.

I get

[image: raster that has 777 at the location marked yellow]

when clicking in the yellow area, which is what I expect. Note: the yellow marking is NOT in the data, it's just for visualisation where I clicked.

You probably need to fine-tune the edges and see whether different resolutions will damage your data somewhat.